# Using GoogleApiClient to implement Automatic SMS Verification Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, google-api-client, sms-retriever-api

Am trying to use GoogleApiClient to implement Automatic SMS Verification Android in a fragment. Am following the official documentation here [Automatic SMS Verification with the SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request)

Am stuck in this part [Obtaining user phone number](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request#1_obtain_the_users_phone_number)

Below is my code and how i have been trying to implement in Android using a fragment where i have an edit text of TextInputEditText for the phone number

My Fragment declarations

```
    TextInputEditText etOtpPhoneNumber;

    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private static final int RESOLVE_HINT = 1;
```

My Fragment implements the following

```
public class smsRetriever extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
```

Finding my views in xml and initializing GoogleApiClient

```
        etOtpPhoneNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.et_otp_phone_number);


        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(requireActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .enableAutoManage(requireActivity(), this)
                .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                .build();
```

My methods

```
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    // Obtain the phone number from the result
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESOLVE_HINT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
                // credential.getId();  <-- will need to process phone number string
            }
        }
    }
```

I am implementing the following method to obtain users phone number which am having a problem with

```
private void requestPhoneNumberHint() {

        HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .build();


        PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
                googleApiClient, hintRequest);



        try {

            startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
                    RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);

        }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

The problem is with startIntentSenderForResult where i am having the below error

```
Expected 7 arguments but found 6
```

According to startIntentSenderForResult method is should implement the following

```
public void startIntentSenderForResult(@SuppressLint("UnknownNullness") IntentSender intent,
            int requestCode, @Nullable Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues,
            int extraFlags, @Nullable Bundle options)
```

What should i put for @Nullable Bundle options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST, null,
                    0, 0, 0, new Bundle());
```

or

```
startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
                    RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
```